# Geb-like Module in Xamarin.UITest?

Tags: geb

My understanding of [Geb modules](https://gebish.org/manual/1.0/#repeating-content) was for groups of elements that always appeared together and were recurring throughout the site. Like a nav-bar and header, or a shopping cart.

I'd like to add this module functionality to several pages I'm working on with [Xamarin.UITest](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/test-cloud/uitest/)

Does anyone know if this is already built in to Xamarin? Has someone already rolled this? Or am I doomed to roll my own?